# Remove left side of graph (from 0 to 13) with scale_x_discrete()

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

The data can be download here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1McbcquHdsdlEM_yPfBQHeX_CpUcARAm1I3VtASNsY3k/edit?usp=sharing

Here is my code

```
# load data
raw_data <- read.csv("Sleep vs reaction time (Responses) - Form Responses 1.csv")

library(ggplot2)

#histogram
qplot(x = Age, data = raw_data, xlim = c(13,43), geom = "histogram") + scale_x_continuous()


qplot(x = Age, data = raw_data, xlim = c(13,43), geom = "histogram") + scale_x_discrete()
```

I would like to draw a histogram by Age.
It is discrete value (age is whole number) so I use scale_x_discrete to separate between bar. However, it look like that
[image: discrete]
which have the space on left side.

If I use scale_x_continuous(), the left space will gone, but the separate between bar also gone too.
[image: continue]

I would like to get rid of the space on left side, from 0 to 13, but keep the separate between bar. Please show me how.

Thank you.

**My solution**: 
Thanked to @Gregor, this is my solution:

```
raw_data$Age = factor(raw_data$Age) #convert Age column to factor
qplot(x = Age, data = raw_data, geom = "histogram") + scale_x_discrete()
```

Result: 
[image: age_hist]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should let the class of your data determine whether the scale is discrete or continuous. `ggplot` doesn't have built-in support for an integer scale as something different from a numeric scale, so if you want a discrete scale you should convert your age data to `factor` (if it's not already):

```
raw_data$Age_factor = factor(raw_data$Age)
```

Then the defaults will give you what you want if you **don't** specify `xlim`.

```
qplot(x = Age_factor, data = raw_data, geom = "histogram")
```

This is a bit confusing, but it was actually your `xlim = c(13, 43)` that was shifting your graph to the right. On a discrete scale, 13 and 43 refer to the 13th and 43rd discrete levels, so by setting those xlim you were forcing your data to the right.

Comment: Gregor, shouldn't that be `x=Age_factor`? Also, you could just do `x=factor(Age)` instead of creating a new column in the data frame.

Comment: Thanks @eipi10, the `Age_factor` is corrected. I prefer converting in the data to conversions inside (the implied) `aes()`, especially when I haven't downloaded OP's data to check it out.